# How to pass a C program as a Command Line Argument

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

Im not sure if it is possible, but would like to know if i can use the result of a main() function as the command line argument for another program. im currently using gcc compiler on linux so i figure it would look something like this:

```sh
./listcommandlinearugments ./generaterandomstring
```

but this does not work... in the above example the first program (listcommandlinearguments) simply lists ./generaterandomstring as a command line arugment instead of using the result of the main funtion (0) because it was int main() and returned 0.

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: yes im using linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands

Comment: CAn you calrify the question? Are you looking for a shell solution, using two programs as-is? Or can you modify the `listcommandlinearugments` source code? The tag suggests that it's C source code.

Comment: i tried  ./listcommandlinearugments | ./generaterandomstring and got no result. the program to list command line arugements should have showed the result of generaterandomstring.c as a command line arugment

Comment: to try and clarify my question, i am trying to use the return 0; from a main function in one program as the command line argument for another program.  So one program returns 0 and the other program returns that 0 was a command line argument

Comment: sorry if im not good at explaining this stuff, im new to programming

Comment: The duplicate notation is for bash.  This is a c question requesting usage of exec.

Comment: @KevinK are you trying to write a bash script to call a c program, or a c program to call another c program?  Your question mentions C, but your tags show bash and not C.

Comment: @netskink i think its a bash script because its a text file that i wrote the code into. the only thing is i ran it through a gcc compiler so its what i think is an executable file now

Answer (score 1):

You can use backticks to insert the output of a program into another command:

```
./generaterandomstring `./listcommandlinearugments`
```

EDIT:

Since you want the return value of the `listcommandlinearugments`, run that first, then use `$?` to get the return value:

```
./generaterandomstring
./listcommandlinearugments $?
```

Comment: Aren't we supposed to prefer `$()` these days?

Comment: i tried this and there was no sign of the program in backticks being run at all. the program to list command line arguments said that there were no additional command line arguments when i executed " ./commandlinearguments (backticks)`./generatearandomstring`(backticks) "

Comment: This actually worked.. somewhat... it passes the string inside of the printf in one program as the command line argument to the other program!!! however i was originally trying to pass the returned value from the first program as the command line argument of another program.. but ill take it! Thx a ton!

Comment: im having trouble getting it to return the return value of the second program. The complexity is that my second program takes one command line argument itself. Example:    i tried this:        ./comandlinearguments ./stringtolowercase HELLO $? and its simply returning ./stringtolowercase, HELLO and 0 as the command line arguments

Comment: i got some functionality with ./commandlinearguments (backtick)./returnzero(backtick)$?   However i cant seem to get it to work with a command line argument for the second function example ./commanlinearguments (backtick)./stringtolowercase HELLO(backtick)$? maybe something is wrong with my code, is that how you would add a command line argument to the second function?